# Getting `error: could not compile `libp2p-noise` due to previous error` while compiling a Substrate project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, substrate

I have been trying to compile a Substarte project but getting this weird error.

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> /Users/ayushkumarmishra/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libp2p-noise-0.32.0/src/protocol/x25519.rs:221:45
    |
221 |         curve25519_sk.copy_from_slice(&hash.as_ref()[..32]);
    |                                        -----^^^^^^--
    |                                        |    |
    |                                        |    cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `AsRef`
    |                                        this method call resolves to `&T`
    |
    = note: type must be known at this point

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
error: could not compile `libp2p-noise` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Can somebody please help me to fix this?

Below is the output of `rustup show`

### installed toolchains

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-08-31-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-11-07-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

### installed targets for active toolchain

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

### active toolchain

nightly-2021-11-07-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

rustc 1.58.0-nightly (072799443 2021-11-06)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the relevant code surrounding the error, and also give the type of `hash` if the relevant code does not make that apparent?

Comment: @IanS. Unfortunately I won't be able to share code. However I am not using this `libp2p-noise` anywhere in my codebase. It must be coming from any other dependencies. 

Its look like it could be because of Rust version.

Comment: You could try updating to the latest nightly but 0.32.0 of `libp2p-noise` was released before 1.58.0-nightly, so I would be surprised if that was the issue. I couldn't find much from searching online but the latest version of `libp2p-noise` [does not have the call to `as_ref`.](https://docs.rs/libp2p-noise/0.35.0/src/libp2p_noise/protocol/x25519.rs.html#222). You can install `cargo tree` to view what's depending on `libp2p-noise` and I'd make sure that dependency is up to date.

Comment: The community looking to support you on these issues is mostly over at https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ - have you tried asking this there?